# Derivative of the stress tensor

Tags: multivariable-calculus, fluid-dynamics

Let $\partial u_i/\partial x_i=0$ then given that

$$\sigma_{ij} = -p\delta_{ij}+\mu\left(\frac{\partial u_i}{\partial x_j}+\frac{\partial u_j}{\partial x_i}\right)$$

Show that

$$\frac{\partial \sigma_{ij}}{\partial x_j} = -(\nabla p)_i+\mu\nabla^2u_i$$

So the solution is:

\begin{align}
\frac{\partial \sigma_{ij}}{\partial x_j} &= \frac{\partial}{\partial x_j} \left(-p\delta_{ij}+\mu\left(\frac{\partial u_i}{\partial x_j}+\frac{\partial u_j}{\partial x_i}\right)\right) \\
&= - \frac{\partial p}{\partial x_j} + \mu\left(\frac{\partial^2 u_i}{\partial x_j\partial x_j}+\frac{\partial^2 u_j}{\partial x_j\partial x_i}\right) \\
&= - \frac{\partial p}{\partial x_j} + \mu\frac{\partial^2 u_i}{\partial x_j\partial x_j} \tag{since $\partial u_i/\partial x_i=0$} \\
&= - (\nabla p)_i + \mu\nabla^2 u_i
\end{align}

---

But why on the first to the second line have we suddenly removed $\delta_{ij}$ (which is the kronecker delta)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\partial_j (p \delta_{ij}) = \partial_j p \delta_{ij} + p \partial_j \delta_{ij} $

but $\delta_{ij}$ is a constant, so its derivative is zero, and we are left with

$\partial_j p \delta_{ij} = \partial_i p$